# Chat como php e ajax em tempo real

Tags: php, ajax

Eu tenho um arquivo de chat. Nele está todas as conversas dos usuários. Quero que quando esse arquivo é modificado sem atualizar a página, o conteúdo mostre ao usuário. É possivel

Comment: A solução é ajax+setTimeout ou até mesmo websocket (esse depende muito do servidor), se sua duvida for mais ampla edite a pergunta com detalhes para que possa ser reaberta. As respostas ali devem resolver seu problema de como usar o Ajax, que até então parece ser o problema principal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim é possível através de *AJAX*.

Para uma versão simples de chat pode fazer um bloco de javascript que faz um pedido *AJAX* à base de dados de X em X segundos através da função `setTimeout` e obtém as conversas só a partir de determinada data/hora. Sempre que obtém informação adiciona por javascript à janela de chat. A pagina `php` que recebe o pedido e devolve os dados tem que ser capaz de devolver so os dados para um utilizador com base nos parâmetros recebidos.